# How to forget a WiFi network that is previously connected to via QR code?

Tags: wi-fi, xiaomi, xiaomi-pocophone-f1, miui-12

My main phone is Pocophone F1 (Android 10, MIUI 12.0.3)

I connected my phone to home WiFi network via QR code, like this:

[image]

It works. And when I click it to show its detail

[image]

There's no the usual "forget/remove this network" button.

On WiFI -> Additional Settings -> Managed saved networks -> the home wifi network isn't listed there.

How should I remove it, then?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my Google Pixel 7.

For me it worked to **uninstall the app that I had used to connect to the network**, which in my case was a QR reader app.